# Does having medical marjuana card override non-smoking?

Tags: canada, british-columbia, medical-marijuana

If someone has a medical marijuana card, can they smoke in areas that don't allow smoking (for example inside restaurants or at work)? I'm curious about Vancouver, BC in particular.

Comment: "No smoking" means exactly that. It's not about what you have some irrelevant permission for, it's about what you do not and cannot have permission to do to others.

Comment: This is two questions in one, and they are largely unconnected. VTC *too broad*. Pick one, remove the other and ask t separately.

Comment: @Nij doesn't medical conditions override some rules, such as needing to smoke marijuana and having a doctors note?

Comment: Again, it's not about you, it's about what you cannot do to other people, regardless of why you want or need to do it to yourself.

Comment: @Nij Umm... That's quite harsh. If you have an issue with a question, then try to improve it yourself. Regardless, from what I can tell, there's only a single question here - can you use medical marijuana in areas that are no-smoking zones. Nothing terrible here.

Comment: Get a patch, make some hash brownies, etc. Leave the restaurant and find a smoking area. I detest the smell of marijuana even more than cigarette smoke, so I hope your scenario isn't legal.

Comment: Not in Colorado, but I don't have access to B.C. law.

Comment: Yes, questions do tend to look very different when they've been edited to remove half of the original text, *exactly as I suggested should be done*. I'm not going to remove one of two questions - that's completely against the intent of the original asker, and they need an opportunity to copy the extra to a new question or to fix the remainder so that it is coherent. I strongly suggest you review the entire history when you are responding to comments made several hours prior to your own, especially when made soon after the question was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have a medical condition doesn't change the rules set by a private establishment or business.

A restaurant can bar all types of smoking (Including Vaping). Your medical condition would not be an exemption to this rule.

Your employer can have terms of employment that would prohibit you from smoking tobacco or even medicinal marijuana. So even thou you have a "doctors note", it doesn't change the fact that your job can randomly drug test you and subsequently fire you for testing positive for marijuana.

Furthermore, while many countries are relaxing drug laws and allowing for recreational and medicinal marijuana. Most still have stipulations that you must smoke it in private.

Answer (score 0):

That card means that the person will not be arrested for smoking marijuana if they smoke marijuana. But they can get thrown out of a building for smoking if they smoke, and smoking marijuana is no exception.

If you need to smoke marijuana, then you need to do the same thing as someone who needs to smoke tobacco: Find a place where it is allowed to smoke.

Comment: Is that really what the card means? I always thought that a medical marijuana card authorized the bearer to *purchase* marijuana, though I suppose it is different in different jurisdictions.

Answer (score -1):

The issue could come down to what the proprietor says, since the BC general law is limited to tobacco ([Tobacco and Vapor Control Products Act](http://www.bclaws.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/96451_01#section2.1), 2.1):

> a person must not smoke tobacco, hold lighted tobacco, use an
>   e-cigarette, or hold an activated e-cigarette

The [medical marijuana law](http://laws.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-2016-230/FullText.html) does not proscribe any particular mode or venue of consumption. Sections 3-7 only address legality of possessing and obtaining.

Since no law prohibits public consumption of medical marijuana, prohibiting a person with a medical condition from taking their medicine could be discriminatory. [The  Human Rights Act](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/h-6/FullText.html) prohibits discrimination based on disability (and other characteristics); the case of [P.G. v. Baton  Rouge Restaurant](http://www.mcmillan.ca/mobile/Obsessive-Compulsive-Restaurant-Requests-The-Customer-Is-Always-Right) is an application of that law. This limits the right of proprietors to govern conduct on their property, just as they may not discriminate in providing service to a person based on race, gender, sexual orientation or religion. Although there has been some call for specific laws addressing the matter, it appears that the strongest restriction is a recommendation from Health Canada that you not smoke marijuana in public.

Comment: **"_Since no law prohibits public consumption of medical marijuana, prohibiting a person with a medical condition from taking their medicine could be discriminatory._"**  Since forcing bystanders to endure an undesired high against their consent would essentially be assault, I don't think that anyone could reasonably claim this to be discrimination.

Comment: @Nat I've certainly never been high from second-hand marijuana smoke, and I have certainly been in situations where I ought to have if it were possible.  I don't find your argument convincing.

Comment: @phoog I dunno what your personal biology's like, but marijuana smoke puts THC in breathers' lungs.  It's basically the same thing as smoking it yourself, just at a lower concentration.  Exactly what that concentration is depends on the situation.

Comment: The downvoter really should say why you think my answer is in error. For example, do you know of a BC statute that outlaws all public smoking?